# Razor template editing in Visual Studio 2010: why all the type inference errors?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, type-inference

I have a strongly-typed view with a `@model` declaration:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

When using extension methods like this in my Razor views:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo)
```

Visual Studio shows errors like this:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

These are only errors shown for the editor window; the view renders just fine at runtime.

Does this happen for *everyone*, or is there something I can do to make the Razor editor work better?

Comment: do you have a custom view page factory?

Comment: are you sure you have a correct @model declaration at the top? can you post an example razor view?

Comment: @mnemosyn, we don't have a custom view page factory.

Comment: @MihalisBagos, I've added my `@model` declaration to the post.  The razor view really only has usings, the model declaration, and markup like the snippet I posted.

Comment: Does it happen for views in both the root and in areas? You could try using the fully qualified name in the `@model` declaration.

Comment: @Charlino, I'm not using areas.  Unfortunately, qualifying the model name with the namespace did not make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7142200/119549), I found the solution.  In my web.config, once I specified a `targetFramework` attribute in my `system.web/compilation` config section, all of those nasty warnings disappeared.  Previously, no `targetFramework` was specified.  Strangely, Visual Studio doesn't just use the target framework of your project:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <!-- ... -->
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just because razor compiler has no idea what type TModel should be.

I get the same errors and just ignore them because, it works so I am happy inside. But you could possibly try something like this, although having written it I think it's retarded and probably epicly useless but maybe someone else can shed some light on why it is retarded and the actual solution to avoiding these errors.

```
public class SomeBlah {
    public Blah blahs { get; set; }
}

public class Blah {
    public string Rawr { get; set; }
}


@model SomeBlah


@Html.TextBoxFor<Blah, string>(s => s.rawr)
```

Comment: I hope to be able to avoid explicit types like this.  Hopefully someone has figured this out.

Comment: I think therein lies the problem, razor likes explicit types =P

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the web.config file in your web project has the correct namespaces imported. There's a chance your deployed website is using a different web.config than the one visual studio is using to parse the razor file.