# All .Net sample apps giving assembly issues

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

Recently a project of mine starting having issues with Linq in its Views.  I couldn't figure out why this was happening so I created another project in VS 2013 using the default Web App template for MVC 4.  Even that was giving me the same issues.  The app runs just fine, but the intellisence isn't referencing the model being used and most references to the model in the View is giving this error:

`The type arguments for method 'System.Web.MVC.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Tmodel>, System.Func<Tmodel,TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage.`

[image]

The project was created with .NET 4.5.1 as its Target framework and can be verified in the project's properties and the web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

I have even tried creating a sample MVC app on another computer and moving it over.  It worked fine on the other computer, but is giving the same error once its opened on my main computer.

Any ideas what is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Sometimes a simple clean on the solution works for me

Comment: @gyosifov I tried that with no luck

Comment: Do you have some extensions on the visual studio that are not present on the other computer? If so try disabling them one by one and see if they are causing the problem.

Comment: See this, it is very similar to what you have : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517669/mvc-view-type-arguments-html-helper-displayfor-cannot-be-inferred-from-the-usag

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for writing here but I don't have enough rep to write in comments.
I had a similar problem that i resolved by changing:

```
<compilation debug="true>
```

To

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Comment: But I am using .NET 4.5.1, why would I target 4.0?

Comment: I was pasted it, must have forgoten to update, the idea was to explicitly state the framework version and see if it works.