# Trying to get a simple class in a Model to return a basic string in the view without Entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and am struggling to get to grips with the basics. Most of my application will not use a database, and the business logic will be stored in the Model. I've tried to get a basic concept working:

My Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Assets()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

My Model:

```
    public class Assets
{
    public class Data
    {
        public string Name {
            get { return "Hello World"; }
            set { Name = "Hello World"; }
        }
    }
}
```

My View:

```
 @model myProject.Models.Assets.Data

<h1>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</h1>
```

It runs fine but instead of showing "Hello World" between the H1 tags, it literally says "Name"

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I've made some edit to my code, try setting up yours like mine it should work

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)`.

Have you ever decorated a model with a `DataAnnotation`? E.g.

```
[Display(Name = "Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

`Html.DisplayNameFor` will render that `Name` property, which by default is the actual property string. For example:

```
public string NameToShow { get; set; }
```

Would render NameToShow as a string

Comment: If I try using DisplayFor, then, Visual Studio gives an error along the lines of "the type arguments for method cannot be inferred from usage". What am I missing?

Comment: @JackofallTrades http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517669/mvc-view-type-arguments-html-helper-displayfor-cannot-be-inferred-from-the-usag

Comment: I'm still at a loss. Everywhere I look, it says: targetFramework="4.6.1"

Comment: However, it does compile, but now nothing is outputted between the <h1> tags

Comment: @JackofallTrades Try removing the setter, you don't need one

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

**Model**

```
 public class Assets
 {
    public Data DaTa {get; set;} ///new line added 

    public class Data
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}           

    }
 }
```

**EDIT**

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Assets()
    {
      var model = new Assets();
      model.DaTa = new Data(); //line edited

       model.DaTa.Name = "Hello World"; //line edited
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model myProject.Models.Assets //second edit

<h1>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Data.Name)</h1> //second edit
```

Comment: The error I'm getting now is "Assets.Data is a type but is used like a variable"

Comment: The top one. The bottom one gives "Data cannot reference a type through an expression"

Comment: @JackofallTrades Ok I missed something so I've added that now, the reason why we were having that error was because I missed a line. I've indicated where the changes are

Comment: I'm still getting the "is a type but is used like a variable" error

Comment: @JackofallTrades make sure `Data` begins with `new`, so should be like `new Data();`

Comment: Yes I am doing that. No uild errors but it's still showing "Name" rather than "Hello World"

Comment: @JackofallTrades I don't why your code is not working but try the `second edit` i have made. It should work

Comment: Now I get an error in the browser... Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'Assets.Data' does not contain a definition for 'Data' and no extension method 'Data' accepting a first argument of type 'Assets.Data' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Take a snapshot of your controller and your view

Comment: Sorry for being thick, but what do you mean by a snapshot?

Comment: @JackofallTrades  screen shot i mean, or print screen if you like, i want to know what exactly you are doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @model myProject.Models.Assets.Data

   <h1>@Model.Name</h1>
```

This will do the work

Comment: I get a NullReferenceException when I try that

Comment: @JackofallTrades that means your model is null do a null check before accessing the model @if(Model != null)

Comment: How can it be null if both get and set are hard coded to "Hello World"?

Comment: @JackofallTrades Name is not null but the model it self. According to the code you have in the top you are not passing model. You have to say return View(new Data());