# One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to compile this code in Microsoft Visual C# 2010

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;


class main
{
    static void Main()
    {

        dynamic d;
        d = "dyna";
        Console.WriteLine(d);    
    }
}
```

but I am getting these two errors

*Error  1   Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported*

*Error 2        One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?*

I read this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115055/why-am-i-getting-one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-can) but I am new to C# and I couldn't understand what really is the problem. Especially what and where are these so called `.config` files..

Comment: Check your References. 

Right click and "Add Reference.." Search for "Microsoft.CSharp.dll" and add it.

Usually System.Core.dll comes standard when you create a new project, not so sure about CSharp.dll

Answer (score 595, accepted):

On your solution explorer window, right click to References, select Add Reference, go to .NET tab, find and add Microsoft.CSharp.

Alternatively add the [Microsoft.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CSharp/) NuGet package.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CSharp
```

Comment: Mine was already referenced yet I still had this error.  I had created a new ASP.Net MVC4 application in VS 2010.  Stumped, I removed and readded it, and the error went away.  Cleaning/Rebuilding did not help.

Comment: @Paul: Same happened to me after upgrading a project from 4.0 to 4.5. Version#/etc is the same between 4.0/4.5 IIRC which might be the reason.

Comment: The Visual Studio team should really think about letting people mouse over the error and then select "Add Microsoft.CSharp to References"

Answer (score 21):

Make sure that your project is targeting the .NET framework 4.0.  Visual Studio 2010 supports .NET 3.5 framework target also, but .NET 3.5 does not support the `dynamic` keyword.

You can adjust the framework version in the project properties.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue except removing and adding the reference back did not fix the error, so I changed .Net version from `4.5` to `4.5.1`.

To achieve this go to your `web.config` file and change the following lines

```html
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

to this

```html
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

and rebuild.

Answer (score 6):

Red lines under the ViewBag was my headache for 3 month ).
Just remove the Microsoft.CSharp reference from project and then add it again.

Comment: this didn't work for me even when I also have red lines in my ViewBag line

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by removing "Microsoft.CSharp" reference from the project and then added it again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, removing and re-adding a reference to Microsoft.CSharp fixed the problem temporarily until the affected file was edited. Closing Visual Studio and reopening the project fixed it more long-term, so that's an option if this situation occurs while Microsoft.CSharp is already referenced.

Maybe restarting the IDE as a first step seems trivial, but here's a reminder for people like me who don't think of that as the first thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me.

My class libraries were definitely all referencing both System.Core and Microsoft.CSharp.  Web Application was 4.0 and couldn't upgrade to 4.5 due to support issues.

I was encountering the error compiling a razor template using the [Razor Engine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine), and only encountering it intermittently, like after web application has been restarted.

The solution that worked for me was manually loading the assembly then reattempting the same operation...

```
        bool retry = true;
        while (retry)
        {
            try
            {
                string textTemplate = File.ReadAllText(templatePath);
                Razor.CompileWithAnonymous(textTemplate, templateFileName);
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (TemplateCompilationException ex)
            {
                LogTemplateException(templatePath, ex);
                retry = false;

                if (ex.Errors.Any(e  => e.ErrorNumber == "CS1969"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _logger.InfoFormat("Attempting to manually load the Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder");
                        Assembly csharp = Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
                        Type type = csharp.GetType("Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder");
                        retry = true;
                    }
                    catch(Exception exLoad)
                    {
                        _logger.Error("Failed to manually load runtime binder", exLoad);
                    }
                }

                if (!retry)
                    throw;
            }
        }
```

Hopefully this might help someone else out there.

Answer (score -2):

If you miss, Microsoft.CSharp.dll this error can occur. Check you project references.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to include a code sample or more of an explanation.  This seems more like a comment,

Comment: You basically said the same thing as in accepted answer given 3 years ago.