# Cast a variable to a Type and call Methods

Tags: c#, reflection, types, casting, keyvaluepair

How would I go about invoking a method call for an Object after casting it to a Type?
I have a KeyValuePair which stores the type of the object and the object itself. I then want to cast this object to its key type and invoke a method of that class type.

```
    KeyValuePair<Type, Object> client = myClients.Find(
        delegate(KeyValuePair<Type, Object> result)
        {
            return (result.Key == myClients[clientNumber].Key); // Match client of the same type
        }
    );

    if (client.Value != null)
    {
        // cast client.Value to type of client.Key, then invoke someMethod 
        client.Key.GetType() v = Convert.ChangeType(client.Value, client.Key.GetType());
        return v.someMethod();
    }
```

Any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not make the object implement an interface with the method defined and then simply do `return ((IMyInterface)client.Value).SomeMethod()`

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
return v.someMethod();
```

you have to call the method by reflection

```
var method = typeof(v).GetMethod("<methodName>",...);

return method.Invoke(v, new[]{<parameters of the method>});
```

Note that `method.Invoke()` will return an object, so you'll have to cast it to the desired type (if needed).

Comment: Hi, I added `var x = (client.Key.GetType()).GetMethods();` but it returns a whole list of methods: `System.Reflection.MethodInfo[163]` none of which are the methods of type `client.Key`. Also my Object only has 4 methods. Any ideas?

Comment: @Travv92 What give you `client.Key.GetType().Name` ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use the `dynamic` keyword:

```
dynamic v = client.Value;
v.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: When I use that I get: `Error 8 One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?`. Any idea why?

Comment: @Travv92: What .NET framework are you using? What version of VS?

Comment: @Travv92: Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725514/one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-cannot-be-found-are

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way, when you're not doing something in bulk, is using the `Type.InvokeMember` method with the right `BindingFlags`.

Answer (score 0):

If someMethod is going to be same in `v.someMethod()`, your keys could implement an interface - and hence you could do away with the `Convert.ChangeType` logic.