# Why doesn't casting "as something.GetType()" work?

Tags: c#, casting

This code results in an error: `type or namespace "index" could not be found`.

```
foreach (var index in Model.UserAssets.Keys)
{
    foreach (var asset in Model.UserAssets[index])
    {
        var val = asset as index.getType();
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this work? Is it because `index` is not in scope (although it should be)?

Comment: Looks like it should be in scope. What do you mean it isn't in scope? Are you getting an error or something else? Be more specific.

Comment: What error are you getting that makes you think its out of scope?

Comment: Sorry. I get the "type or namespace index could not be found".

Comment: You can't use `as` like that. It's evaluated at compile-time. You can only use it to cast to specific type, not "the type of this object".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *variable* `index` *is* in scope, but `as` *only* allows a Type: `expr as T`.

So in `asset as index.getType()`, the compiler is attempting to treat `index` like a type, which it is not, and never even considers that there is a variable with the given name.

---

Trying to cast (including using `as`) on run-time type information, such as included in a Type instance, generally doesn't make sense. For why, and alternatives, consider

- [Typecasting base class reference to its actual type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524632/c-typecasting-base-class-reference-to-its-actual-type?lq=1)
- [How to cast object to type described by Type class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206148/how-to-cast-object-to-type-described-by-type-class?rq=1)
- [How to cast an object value to Type values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975090/how-to-cast-an-object-value-to-type-values?lq=1)
- [Cast a variable to a Type and call Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735887/cast-a-variable-to-a-type-and-call-methods?rq=1)

Comment: index is a type in my case. My dictionary is Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<...>>.

Comment: @user3750107 `index` is a *variable* of which `index.getType()` presumable returns an *expression of Type*; not a Type.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, the variable index is in scope, but you're trying to treat the Type object as a Type. This isn't quite the case - GetType() returns an object of the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) class, used for reflection. An object of thus can also be return using the typeof() statement.

Both is and as are keyword which support direct Type checking, which works differently and must be a direct class reference. If you wish, however, you could compile a lambda representing the above statement using Expressions, wherein it will dynamically build your statement at runtime.

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

...
if(index.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(asset.GetType())) return; // This will prevent an InvlaidCatException
var param = Expression.Parameter(asset.GetType());
var exp = Expression
    .Convert(
        param,
        index.GetType());
var del = Expression.Lambda(exp, param).Compile();
var val = del.DynamicInvoke(index);
```