# How to access Properties of different objects with no common ancestor using a Generic object?

Tags: c#, object, generics

I have this code, basically it set the same properties in the "X"HttpBinding.

```
switch (serviceEndpoint.Binding.GetType().ToString())
{
case "System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding":
    WSHttpBinding _wsBinding = (WSHttpBinding)serviceEndpoint.Binding;
    _wsBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = maxSize;
    _wsBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxSize;
    _wsBinding.OpenTimeout = timeOut;
    _wsBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = maxSize;
    break;

case "System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding":
    WebHttpBinding _webBinding = (WebHttpBinding)serviceEndpoint.Binding;
    _webBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = maxSize;
    _webBinding.MaxBufferSize = maxSize;
    _webBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxSize;
    _webBinding.OpenTimeout = timeOut;
    break;

default:
case "System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding":
    BasicHttpBinding _basicBinding = (BasicHttpBinding)serviceEndpoint.Binding;
    _basicBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = maxSize;
    _basicBinding.MaxBufferSize = maxSize;
    _basicBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxSize;
    _basicBinding.OpenTimeout = timeOut;
    break;
}
```

Object `serviceEndpoint.Binding` could be different each time.

I want to know, if I could do something like:

```
object _Binding = serviceEndpoint.Binding;
_Binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = maxSize;
_Binding.MaxBufferSize = maxSize;
_Binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxSize;
_Binding.OpenTimeout = timeOut;
```

But if I put this, I have an error because i don't get the properties of the cast object.

Comment: Doing a switch-case on a type's *name* is *reeallly* bad. Consider using the `is` operator instead: `if(serviceEndpoint.Binding is WebHttpBinding)`. Or safe casts - `var webBinding = serviceEndpoint.Binding as WebHttpBinding; if(webBinding != null) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, those properties aren't defined on a common ancestor, so the only way left is using reflection. The `dynamic` keyword is a nice shortcut:

```
dynamic binding = serviceEndpoint.Binding;

binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = maxSize;
binding.MaxBufferSize = maxSize;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxSize;
binding.OpenTimeout = timeOut;
```

But by doing so, you lose the ability to detect cast errors at compile time. It's up to you to decide whether it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply KooKiz, i try with  dynamic keyword but when I build  the proyect I get this error "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you  missing a reference?" I'm trying with       dynamic _Binding = serviceEndpoint.Binding;
                _Binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = maxSize;

Comment: Make sure you have a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` in your project. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11725576/869621