# one or more types required to compile a dynamic expression c#

Tags: c#

I have already looked at: [One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725514/one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-cannot-be-found-are) but after trying the top solution as well as other solutions I've researched I am still unable to resolve this error. My VS is targeting .NET 4.5.1. In addition, the reference to CSharp is added as well. Why am I still getting this error?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net;
using Important.CoreInterfaces;
using Adaptive.SimpleBinaryEncoding;

private static T method<T>(byte[] pinned_memory, ref int offset)
            {
                //dynamic var = typeof(T);
                dynamic temp = 1;
                DirectBuffer tempd = new DirectBuffer(pinned_memory);
                char messageType = (char)pinned_memory[offset];
                switch(messageType)
                {
                    case 'H':
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                        doOtherStuff();
                        break;
                    case 'A':
                        stuff();
                        break;
                    case 'M':
                        break;
                    case 'P':
                        break;
                    case 'F':
                        break;
                    case 'K':
                        break;
                    case 'O':
                        break;
                    case 'C':
                        break;
                    case 'X':
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                MessageHeaderEncoder header = new MessageHeaderEncoder();
                header.Wrap(tempd, offset, 1);
                temp.WrapForDecode(tempd, offset, temp.sbeBlockLength(), temp.sbeSchemaVersion()); 
            }
```

Comment: Can you include your 'using' statements please?

Comment: added them in my edit

Comment: You can look in the event log, which might have more details about the error. For sure, you have not provided enough information here for anyone to be able to answer the question, at least not in any more detail than the questions you've already looked at. You need to debug this and figure out on your own which type(s) is(are) not available.

Comment: do you have any recommendations on what to add to the question?