# calling nongeneric method on generic type determined at runtime c#

Tags: c#, generics

I want to call a non-generic method on a generic type. This is because I know that type T at runtime will definitely have said method. c# does not allow this so I looked up solutions but I have found none that have solved this problem.

1) I tried using dynamic types but ran into a problem to which I still haven't found an answer: [one or more types required to compile a dynamic expression c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325797/one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment50637994_31325797)

2) I have tried defining an interface in which I defined delegates that I instantiated in generic_method. This does not work because in generic_method I was unable to access the delegate even though I passed it in to the function.

```
private interface MessageMethods
{
    public delegate void MethodDelegate(DirectBuffer buffer, int offset, int actingBlockLength, int actingVersion); 
}

private static T generic_method<T>(byte[] pinned_memory, ref int offset) where T: MessageMethods
{
    MethodDelegate m = new MethodDelegate(someFunctionSomewhereElse()); 
    // Visual studio does not recognize what MethodDelegate is, so this does not work.

    // someFunctionSomewhereElse() is NOT generic
}
```

I have looked at problems using reflection, but this is the first time I've dealt with generic types to this degree and unfortunately I am having a difficult time understanding how to use reflection in C#. What else can I try?

Comment: where does `generic_method<T>` live? it's part of some larger class, yes?

Comment: yes it is part of a larger class

Comment: You need to provide somewhat more compilable sample (probably 5 more lines will get it there)... So far looks nothing related to generics - `new MessageMethods.MethodDelegate(someFunctionSomewhereElse)` should solve your current issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not completely clear from the formatting of the code, but I think that this is your issue:

MethodDelegate is a delegate that is in a private interface MessageMethods.

You should make your interface public and in your generic_method, use the following syntax:

```
private static T generic_method<T>(byte[] pinned_memory, ref int offset) where T : MessageMethods
{
    MessageMethods.MethodDelegate m = new MessageMethods.MethodDelegate(someFunctionSomewhereElse); // also, don't use the extra (), because you probably don't want to call the method yet.
}
```

Comment: I don't have an issue doing this but for my own understanding why couldn't I keep MessageMethods private? I thought private still meant members of the same class had access to it.

Comment: Is `generic_method` inside of `MessageMethods`?

Comment: No generic_method and MessageMethods are part of the same class. I understand that since generic_method is static that it's not actually associated with an instance of the class whereas the non-static interface is associated with the class but then again how would generic_method find the interface?

Comment: That would be something I would need to find out as well. I'm not completely sure about inner classes. But normally you would.