# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject one or more types for dynamic expression cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to Deserialize an Object using JsonConvert.

I have the following:

```
dynamic jsonBitlyResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ShortenedURLStreamReader);
string ShortenedURLstring = jsonBitlyResponse.data.ToString();
```

But I get the following error when I try and build it:

> one or more types to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found

I made a test aspx.cs page for this application and it worked fine, but when I try to add it to a .cs page, it gives me the error.

All the same imprts are in the .cs page as the .aspx.cs page - so I have absolutely no idea what the problem is.

I have tried adding in the recommend DLL's, but this also does not help.

I have not idea what the problem is - any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725514/one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-cannot-be-found-are

Comment: @AshishRajput It says in the question that I have already added all the recommended DLL's