# JS like enumaration in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, enumeration

In JavaScript I can have an array of different objects in each cell, and when enumerating it each cell will get treated as the object it is and not as an underlying common object of the collection.

Lets say I have 2 objects:

```
class car
{
    public color;
    ...
}

class paint
{
    public color;
    ...
}
```

Is there a syntax for an enumaration like

```
car beemer;
paint panda;
...
foreach (thing in [beemer, panda])
{
    thing.color = "red";
}
```

in c#?

Comment: Could you provide a *complete* example of JavaScript code which you'd like to mimic in C#?

Comment: [beemer, panda] is just JS for an array. C# arrays?

Comment: Use an `interface` for this kind of thing.

Comment: @DavidG the objects are in a blackbox dll

Comment: @DvS how can I define an array that accepts different objects as cells?

Comment: @SharonJDDorot It's really unusual to have to treat multiple types of object with the same action like this. First, are you sure these classes don't already implement the same interface?

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic that seems like a reasonable solution but I really hate tuples... :D

Comment: @SharonJDDorot If it is different types, then the array needs to be of type `object`. But it depends what you need to do. If you need to act on those instances in specific ways, then you need to implement one or more interfaces so the types can be treated the same (polymorphism)

Comment: @DavidG yes. It is just a case of me wanting to clean up the code. All these objects contain the same events and are registered to the same method. Instead of registering them one by one, i'd like to loop them.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic One can't enumerate a Tuple (except through reflection)

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can use dynamic typing if you really want:

```
public class Paint
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

...

var objects = new object[]
{
    new Car { Color = "Red" },
    new Panda { Color = "Black" }
};
foreach (dynamic value in objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.Color);
}
```

But it would be more conventional to declare an interface with the property you want, and then make all the relevant types implement the interface:

```
public interface IColored
{
    string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Paint : IColored
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Car : IColored
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

...

var objects = new IColored[]
{
    new Car { Color = "Red" },
    new Panda { Color = "Black" }
};
foreach (IColored value in objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.Color);
}
```

This is:

- More efficient
- Safer, as then you know at compile-time that every value you're iterating over has a `Color` property.

Comment: If I treat a cell in an array of objects as dynamic, it will guve me all the original properties of the custom object?

Comment: @SharonJDDorot: Yes - the value of the array is just a reference to the object...

Comment: gives me a compilation error: One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?"

Comment: @SharonJDDorot: Well it sounds like you may not have all the references you need, such as `Microsoft.CSharp` or `System.Dynamic` (from memory... could bee wrong). It doesn't help that we don't know *anything* about the type of project you're building, what version of the framework you're using, what version of Visual Studio you're using, etc... But search for that error message and you'll get a lot of hits, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725514

Answer (score 3):

If you implement an interface with the color property defined on the interface will be able to achieve this.

```
public interface IHasColor 
{
  string color { get; set; }
}

public class car : IHasColor
{
    public color { get; set; }
    ...
}

foreach (IHasColor thing in new IHasColor[] { beemer, panda })
{
    thing.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: These objects come from a blackboxed dll

Comment: Then inheritance may solve this, create your own versions of the classes and implement the interface on there