# Warning messages in VS 2010 with MVC 4 about missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll & System.Core.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently getting the following warning:

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?

It causes intellisense to go crazy in all my .cshtml files.  However, everything works just fine.  This project was originally created as a MVC 4 project.

I've tried to remove both DLLs and re-add them to ensure they are v4.0.

The target framework is also v4.0 in the web.config file.

I cannot seem to get rid of the warning.  Any ideas?

Comment: Previously I have gotten these same symptoms, but I have no idea what I did to cause it.  Shutting down VS and restarting/reopening the solution resolved it.

Comment: I've had this issue for about 2 or 3 weeks now...  So I've turned my computer off and still get the issue.

Comment: I installed it from asp.net...  I tried to reinstall it and still same issue.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115055/why-am-i-getting-one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-can][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115055/why-am-i-getting-one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-can

Comment: Closing VS fixed it for myself too when we had this happen. Personally MVC4 is a massive pain with its crazy amount of dependencies, whether you use them or not. With each version of the framework the MVC dependencies seems to increase, which in turn causes issues like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what happened is that the web.config file got saved in unicode format and the version of mvc had a weird character in it so it was hidden from view.  Once I deleted that character, it all worked again.