# How to convert dynamic null boolean value to false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor, razor-2

I'm creating ASP.NET MVC4 C# application which accepts dynamic queries and generates razor views dynamically.

Application uses WebMatrix.Data.Query() to get data. This method returns `IEnumerable<dynamic>` .
Result rows can contain bool? type properties whise value is null.

Those values are used in dynamically generated razor views with && , || and ! operators.
Those operatos does not accept null boolean values, runtime exception occurs in this case.

I'm looking for a way to fix this.
It seems that best way is to convert dynamic boolean null values to false.

I tried  method

```
    public static dynamic BooleanNullToFalse(dynamic value)
    {
        if (value == null && value is bool?)
            return false;
        return value;
    }
```

but got strange compile error

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be
>   found. Are you missing a reference?

in expression `value == null`

How to fix this so that code compiles ?

Another possibility would be to force `&&`, `||` and `!` boolean operators to accept null values or define
new boolean operators which accept null values. I dont know is this possible/reasonable?

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, but is there a reason your method takes a dynamic as a parameter instead of a Nullable<bool> ? - the name seems to suggest that it only operates on Bool?  Converting earlier will probably go a long way towards solving your problem

Comment: Does your project have reference to Microsoft.CSharp.dll?

Comment: If `value` is an `object`/`dynamic` that can only come from a `bool?`, `value is bool?` is the same as `value != null` due to how boxing works. Your `if` statement will never evaluate true (as described).

Comment: Might want to check the version of it.  Also check out this stackoverflow answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115055/why-am-i-getting-one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-can

Comment: @Tim S If if will never evaluate to true why compiler does not show warning like in other cases ? Is this C# compiler issue ?

Comment: The compiler isn't able, nor does it attempt, to provide warnings in *every* case like this. It does it with some obvious, definite things that it knows how to check for. This is not very obvious (if it's `dynamic`, the compiler doesn't know hardly anything about it) or definite (`value` changes between the evaluations of `value == null` and `value is bool?`, maybe it'll be `true` after all). Doesn't mean it might not still be some wonky logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Microsoft.CSharp reference to your project, and if it is already present then remove and re-add it as per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725514/one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-cannot-be-found-are#comment22088512_11725576).