# The name 'model' does not exist in the current context MVC 4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4 so i dont know why i am getting this error  " The name 'model' does not exist in the current context" please help

```
         @foreach (var item in model)
         {
         <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mobile)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" id="LinkEdit+@item.ID"  onclick="OpenDialog('/Company/UpdateCompany?ID=@item.ID',600,800);" > Edit </a>|
            <a href="#" id="LinkDelete+@item.ID"  onclick="DeleteCompany(@item.ID)" > Delete </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `model` it should be `Model` in foreach loop as :--

```
@foreach (var item in Model){ ..... }
```

Comment: I have changed it but now i am getting another error   "Error 2 The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. d:\11ITAccountPro\11ITAccountPro\11ITAccountPro\Views\ClientMaster\ViewClientDetails.cshtml 43 18 11ITAccountPro
"

Comment: @DineshChauhan...instead of DisplayFor try DisplayNameFor

Comment: @DineshChauhan...this is the problem with your MVC framework not the answer..see this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115055/why-am-i-getting-one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-can/7142200#7142200

Comment: @DineshChauhan...i think.. the problem is that your project still compiled with .NET v3.5 instead of v4.0...see above link also...if answer solved your question then plz accept the answer so that it may help others also..thanks...

Comment: @DineshChauhan..above answer is correct answer of your question(as you mentioned in above comments) so accept it by clicking on tick appearing just below the answer...so that others users can get benefit of the above answer and question..thanks...