# mvc3 razor syntax is missing a type in order to compile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My code was working correctly in Visual Studios Express 2013 until I hit **rebuilt** and then all of the razor syntax on every page has a red squiggly line underneath now. How can I undo this? This all happened when I clicked **rebuilt** the error i'm getting is

```
 One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
```

I normally just click on **built** if I make changes to the controller to compile but this time I clicked rebuilt and it looks like it has done something to my razor syntax. Any suggestions would be great..

Comment: you are missing some reference, check the details of exception it will give you an idea about the missng reference

Comment: Some similar questions with accepted answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115055/why-am-i-getting-one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-can) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725514/one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-cannot-be-found-are) may help

Comment: Thanks just solved the answer by doing that