# Viewbag.Title error: One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. In every .cshtml view file i get the following error for *Viewbag*: **One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?**

I have references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll.

Here is my root web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="RouteDebugger:Disabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <globalization culture="ro-RO" uiCulture="ro" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.0.0" newVersion="3.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Here is the web.config from the Views folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
            <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I can build the solution, and the web application works as expected, but I keep getting this error in the IDE and it's very annoying. I spent the entire day trying to solve this issue. Can someone please tell me how to fix it?

### Edit:

When everything works well, when I navigate to definition (F12) of the ViewBag, I get the `Assembly System.Web.Mvc.dll, v5.1.0.0` from `Recipes.Web\Bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll` and there are 4 using statements, one of which is `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`.

When the error appears, when I navigate to definition (F12) of the ViewBag, I get the same `Assembly System.Web.Mvc.dll, v5.1.0.0` from `Recipes.Web\Bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll`, BUT there are only 3 using statements, `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` is gone.

Sometimes, the error doesn't appear, but if I close the solution and Visual Studio then reopen the solution, the error appears again. I don't even rebuild or do anything else.

Why is this happening?

Comment: did you try to upgrade you project

Comment: what do you mean by upgrade? I have all the nuget packages up to date (aspnet.mvc - 5.1.2, aspnet.razor - 3.1.2, aspnet.webpages - 3.1.2). I have a hunch that this might be the reason for the error. Before updating the nuget packages, the IDE and the extentions and making a few changes to the application, everything worked just fine.

Comment: I ended up reversing the last commits and the error disappeared. The sad part is that I had to make the changes again. I don't know what went wrong and what caused the error.

Comment: Now it happens again ... and I don't know why!

Comment: in think you can try any one of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605263/viewbag-title-error

Comment: I tried all of those answers ...

Comment: I'm reaching here, but have you confirmed that your MVC project's reference to System.Web.Mvc points **Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll**? I've done the nuget upgrade all solution wide and have no issues. I've seen issues when upgrades happen for individual projects.

Comment: Yes the MVC project's reference to System.Web.Mvc path is packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll. And have done the upgrade solution wide, not project by project. I even did an Update-Package –reinstall ...

Answer (score 17):

I do not have this problem when running VS 2012 as administrator.

Otherwise, what worked for me:

1. in root web config have added as recommended reference to correct assembly as child of compilation node
   `<system.web>  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">  <assemblies>  <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />  </assemblies></compilation>  </system.web>`
2. set copy `local = true` properties  for `System.Core`  and `Microsoft.CSharp`

Comment: Do you mean Microsoft.CSharp... because I am not finding a system.Csharp to reference

Comment: Thanks. This helped with some Linq issues I was seeing in Razor too. I had tried deleting 3.5 System.Core from GAC. Anyway this last straw righted the ship.

Comment: Can some one put the line from web.config that needs to be changed for `local = true case`? –

Comment: Just after adding the targetFramework line. ViewBag is resolved.

Comment: @Unbreakable - go to References in your VS project, select the reference you want to set to local, right click and select Properties, then you'll see the Copy Local setting, set it to true.

Answer (score 11):

For reference `Microsoft.CSharp`, change the value of property `Copy Local` from False to True.

Comment: This worked for me, and solved another problem with impersonation

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks a million!

Comment: can some one put the line from web.config that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after I made a code change on the cshtml page with a syntax error.  After correcting the syntax error, the errors persisted.  So, I closed the cshtml and re-compiled... success.  I reopened the cshtml and the errors were no longer there.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help someone. Works for me in VS 2013 with asp.net MVC 5 and .NET 4.6.1

Readding `Microsoft.CSharp` did not fix the problem. Also, adding `System.Core` to `system.web/compilation/assemblies/` at web.config did not fix too.

I overcame this only this adding `System.Web.Mvc` to `system.web/compilation/assemblies/` section:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
  <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Rebuilded the solution and red line disappeared.

Comment: For me (Mvc 4 + .NET 4.5.1) it was enough to remove the `System.Web.Mvc` reference and re-add it manually. If you use nuget, its in the ~/packages folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to Application_Start() method in global.asax

**ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());**

Comment: I have a custom razor view engine that inherits BuildManagerViewEngine. And I have this in global.asax: 
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomRazorViewEngine());

Comment: The problem still occurs ? Your CustomRazorViewEngine inherits from RazorViewEngine, so if this doesnt help it's not the solution to your problem

Comment: This is what solved the problem at my project. I added the following to the web.config

`<system.web> 
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"> 
<assemblies> 
<add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /> 
</assemblies> 
</system.web>
`

Comment: It is a child of <compilation> !