# ASP.NET MVC 5 ViewBag Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewbag

Right now I'm getting a really annoying error, in a view that I'm adding from my Controllers method.

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening??

It works just fine with my other projects just an hour ago!

this is what I did:

1. Create a Model
2. Run Build MyApp
3. Creating a Controller
4. Right click in the Index method to add a View
5. View gets  generated
6. I'm getting the above error! I cant access my model either when sending it to the View!

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Added new pic that shows the error message :)

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725514/one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-cannot-be-found-are

Comment: Doesn't have an answer, but basically It's the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974183/viewbag-title-error-one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression

Comment: can you post the error message ?

Comment: Can you try to remove and re-add the Microsoft.CSharp reference?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ViewData["Title"] = "Index";